# How to determine if an argment was provided to boost::program_options, or if the default is used instead?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Using `boost::program_options`, I need to set the `default_value` for having that default visible in the help message. However, it is still needed to know if the default was applied or if an argument was provided. (The logic will, in certain cases override an existing configuration if the argument pas provided).

Possible solutions:

- Remove default values: but then the help message will not show the default.
- Find a way to check if an argument was provided (How?)
- Create the `option_description` twice (one with defaults, another without). Not ideal.

  ```
  int main( int argc, char* argv[])
  {
      namespace po = boost::program_options;
      namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

      std::string ip;
      std::string port;

      const std::string ip_arg = "ip";
      const std::string port_arg = "ip";

      po::options_description options("Options");
      options.add_options()
      (ip_arg, po::value<std::string>(&ip, "IP")->default_value("127.0.0.1")
      (port_arg, po::value<std::string>(&port, "Port")->default_value("80"))
      ;

      po::variables_map vm;
      try
      {
          using bs = po::command_line_style::style_t;

          boost::program_options::store(
          boost::program_options::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
              .options(options)
              .style(bs::long_allow_next | bs::allow_long | bs::allow_short | bs::allow_dash_for_short | 
                   bs::long_allow_adjacent | bs::short_allow_adjacent | bs::short_allow_next | bs::allow_long_disguise)
              .run(),
              vm);

          po::notify(vm);
      }
      catch( ...)
      {
          std::cerr << "Some error" << std::endl;
          return 1;
      }

      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << options;
      std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl; // Print help, visible defaults

      if (vm.count(port_arg))
      {
          // Argument was provided, so make something
      }
      else
      {
          // Argument was no provided, make something else.
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

---

How can I detect if an argument was provided, or if the default was applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options descriptions are broken. Let's fix them. I opted against the `ip_arg`/`port_arg` variables (note how you had them copy pasted wrong anyways).

```
po::options_description options("Options");
options.add_options()
    ("ip", po::value<std::string>(&ip)->default_value("127.0.0.1"), "IP") //
    ("port", po::value<std::string>(&port)->default_value("80"), "Port")
 ;
```

Now you can be sure that `port` is always set, so `.count()` or `.contains()` are redundant. Instead, ask the map entry whether it has been defaulted:

```
if (vm["port"].defaulted()) {
    std::cout << "Port defaulted (" << port << ")\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "Port specified as " << port << "\n";
}
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd9209094b010f31)**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace po = boost::program_options;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string ip;
    std::string port;

    po::options_description options("Options");
    options.add_options()
        ("ip", po::value<std::string>(&ip)->default_value("127.0.0.1"), "IP") //
        ("port", po::value<std::string>(&port)->default_value("80"), "Port")
     ;

    po::variables_map vm;
    try {
        using bs = po::command_line_style::style_t;

        boost::program_options::store(
            boost::program_options::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
                .options(options)
                .style(bs::long_allow_next | bs::allow_long | bs::allow_short |
                       bs::allow_dash_for_short | bs::long_allow_adjacent |
                       bs::short_allow_adjacent | bs::short_allow_next |
                       bs::allow_long_disguise)
                .run(),
            vm);

        po::notify(vm);
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Some error" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << options << std::endl;

    if (vm["port"].defaulted()) {
        std::cout << "Port defaulted (" << port << ")\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Port specified as " << port << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
$ ./test --ip=192.168.1.2
Options:
  --ip arg (=127.0.0.1) IP
  --port arg (=80)      Port

Port defaulted (80)
```

or

```
$ ./test --port=8080
Options:
  --ip arg (=127.0.0.1) IP
  --port arg (=80)      Port

Port specified as 8080
```

Comment: That difference between `count` and `defaulted` got me crazy. Thank you for you nice explanation and answer.

Comment: The confusion is very understandable. You just forgot to look beyond where you expected it to live. I guess that's a usability concern with the library, but as with most Boost libraries, usability takes a second seat to flexibility and genericity.